# 'environment' and 'directory' options in Supervisord

Tags: python, uwsgi, supervisord

I am using [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to manage a uwsgi process on a server, and I came across these two options: `environment` and `directory` for running a program using Supervisord.

I look at the [docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html), but still not sure what exactly they do. To clarify, the context here is that I am running a web2py app with uwsgi. And inside the config for uwsgi, I've already set the PYTHONPATH and the virtualenv it should run with.

Can someone please explain what these two options are for and how do I set them if necessary?

Comment: Did you read the description of them in [the documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html)?

Comment: Do you have an actual problem we need to help you solve, or do you need help understanding the concepts of environment and directory in the context of Operating System principles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both options are well documented (see [Subprocess Environment](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment) and [the configuration file documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html)).

What it comes down to is that these two options let you set the current working directory and the full environment for the subprocesses that supervisord starts. These are two basic UNIX concepts and many processes may behave differently depending on how these are set. See [Working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) and [Environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) on Wikipedia for in-depth discussion of those concepts.

Generally, if your uwsgi process is running properly, there is no need to tinker with these at all.

If you do need to set them, just add the entries to your configuration, setting `directory` to an existing path on your system and the `environment` value to a set of KEY=VALUE pairs joined by commas.